# How to integrate comment in portlet in liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay-6

I developed a new portlet to display journal article. Now I want to allow users to comment on a journal article.

There is built-in comment feature I saw in the Asset Publisher. How can I integrate the comment feature in my portlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Liferay's tag `<liferay-ui:discussion>`.

Refer to [Link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6723626)